# Server does not get into the if statement, it structs. Socket programming in C

Tags: c, if-statement, socket.io

I want to compare some data that the client sends to a server. But my server got stuck after the random function in my result function. It does nos printf (printf("Into IF");) or get into the ifs, why is this?

> Waiting for incoming connections...Press Ctrl+C to end server
>
> Connection from 127.0.0.1, port 60697 Message Recieved:c Ramdom es 12

My code:

```
void
result(int sockfd)
{
    ssize_t     n;
    char        buf[MAXLINE];
    int         temp;
    time_t      ticks;
    int         i;
again:
    while ((n =read(sockfd, buf, MAXLINE)> 0))
    {
     buf[n] = '\0';
     printf("Message Recieved:%s\n",buf);
     srand (time(NULL));
     temp = rand() % 15+1;
     printf("Ramdom es %i\n",temp);
     printf("Into IF");  
     if ((strncmp (buf,"A",1) == 0) || (strncmp (buf,"a",1) == 0))
     {
      snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "You choose -%i tymes optin A on %.24s\r\n", temp,ctime(&ticks));
      Writen(sockfd, buf, n);

     }
     else if ((strncmp (buf,"B",1) == 0) || (strncmp (buf,"b",1) == 0))
     {
      snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "You choose -%i tymes optin B on on %.24s\r\n", temp,ctime(&ticks));
      Writen(sockfd, buf, n);

     }
     else
     {
       printf("Incorrect Input");
       Close(sockfd);
       break;
     }  
    }
    if (n < 0 && errno == EINTR)
    goto again;
    else if (n < 0)
        err_sys("read error");

}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int                 listenfd, connfd;
    socklen_t           len;
    struct sockaddr_in  servaddr, cliaddr;
    char                buff[MAXLINE];
    /*char                message[MAXLINE];*/
    char                recvline[MAXLINE + 1];

    listenfd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);/*----------------------------------------------------*/
    servaddr.sin_port        = htons(5678); 

    Bind(listenfd, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    Listen(listenfd, LISTENQ);
    printf("Server is running on 127.0.0.1, listening on port 5678\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Waiting for incoming connections...Press Ctrl+C to end server\n");

    for ( ; ; )
    {
        len = sizeof(cliaddr);
        connfd = Accept(listenfd, (SA *) &cliaddr, &len);

        /*Client connects to server*/
        printf("\n");
        printf("Connection from %s, port %d\n",
               Inet_ntop(AF_INET, &cliaddr.sin_addr, buff, sizeof(buff)),
               ntohs(cliaddr.sin_port));

        result(connfd);
            Close(connfd);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The expression `n = read(sockfd, buf, MAXLINE) > 0` looks very wrong as it's parsed like `n = (read(sockfd, buf, MAXLINE) > 0)`. Check the placement of parenthesis.

Comment: The fact that any number of socket library functions are erroneously capitalized cannot be helping (but again, probably not the instant problem).  And I don't know what this "Writen" thing is.  Please post a *complete* test program, one that can be compiled and run without us having to edit it *at all*.

Comment: @Zack...they are capital letter because there are other functions that call the actual socket function but verify for errors.

Answer (score 1):

To print the `printf` add a "\n" (linefeed) so that terminal flushes and displays it. There are several occasions in your code where a \n will help your debug-printfs coming out.

This answers "why does printf does not printf". I think this is not your real problem though.

Comment: Perfect! I added the "\n" at the end and I see that gets into the first if, it seems it send the frame, but the receiver is not reading it....What could be?

Comment: See the comments - to get a better answer try to improve your question -> with edits or create a new question which is more specific and smaller and shows that you have thought and debugged a little bit more on your own.